# Transport mode for ESP of IPsec and use AES?

Tags: windows-xp

1. What is the disadvantage and advantage of [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)-128, AES-192, and AES-256?
2. Does a long key mean good security?

Answer (score 0):

1. Long bit lengths generally take a long time to encrypt/decrypt (not always true).
2. Longer bit length generally means better security; again not always true.